# Unable to create ButtonField event handler nested in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, event-handling

**The problem:** I got a gridview which is populated with product data stemming from a database. Within that gridview is nested a "ButtonField" (in the last column) to be able to add the entire row content as an object to a List if the user clicks on the ButtonField (*Add to cart*). In "Design View" when using double-click on that button I always end up in...

```
protected void gview_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.Write("This WORKS!");
        }
```

...instead of that the correct event handler for the button is generated (which I assume would be looking somewhat like this).

```
protected void gview_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            List<GridViewRow> gvrowobjlist = new List<GridViewRow>();


            if (e.CommandName == "Add to cart")
            {
                GridViewRow gvrow = gview.SelectedRow;
                gvrowobjlist.Add(gvrow);

                //Response.Write("This WORKS as well!!!!!!");
            }

        }
```

Thus the issue here seems to be that it isn't possible to actually access an element (BoundField) in an element (GridView) so the above code is created. Doing so manually in the code behind results in a non-working event handler (tried and failed).

**The question:** What am i doing wrong and how can the event handler be created correctly so it's possible to add objects to the list? Could the problem be related to the combination of BoundFields with a ButtonField? *PS. I have looked for a possible duplicate here but there was nothing that fit the issue at hand.*

```
<asp:GridView ID="gview" runat="server" CellPadding="15" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HorizontalAlign="Center" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVbResult_SelectedIndexChanged">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="prodId" HeaderText="Product ID" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="160px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="prodName" HeaderText="Product Name" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="150px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="packNo" HeaderText="Package amount" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="bxCont" HeaderText="Box Content" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-Width="100" >
                    <ItemStyle Width="100px"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
             <asp:ButtonField Text="addToCart" ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Add to cart" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: But you do not sing up for the RowCommand event, why do you expect it's handler to be triggered?

Comment: Maybe I am a bit slow today but I do not follow you. Could you elaborate, please? Thanks.

Comment: In your code snippet you have ` OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVbResult_SelectedIndexChanged"` which sings up a handler to the event. You do not have the same for Row Command

Comment: I just suddenly realized it after your last post. You are absolutely right. I added it in the HMTL of the gridview and it now triggers the event. Thank you so much! Also I can add for others having the same issue when unable to create the event handler of an element in an element - don't forget to add the above mentioned to the gridview yourself as it isn't auto-generated.

Comment: Andrei I would like to rate your answer as the correct one but you have got to post one instead of a comment if you are interested in that. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I do not think there is a good answer in this. It looks like a typo-style problem to me, and it would be hard to turn this into a useful answer

Comment: You're right. It's maybe not a typo as such but more of a technical error. I still feel though that it could be useful to others running into this issue as its vital to functionality in the final analysis and will surely be missed by many to come. But thanks a lot once again for taking the time and showing the effort. I sincerely appreciate it. :-)

Comment: Okay, I agree there is something in here. Tried to give some additional details and converted this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a second look at the GridView declaration, removing unnecessary parts.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gview" runat="server"
              ...
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvVbResult_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

So there is a handler declared for the index changed event, however none is declared for row command. Existence of the handler does not mean anything, from ASP.NET standpoint this is just another method of the page class, it does connect the handler with the control's event. Even though this handler follows standard naming convention.

To resolve this, simply sing up for the row command event:

```
OnRowCommand="gview_RowCommand"
```

On a side note. You are probably misled here by the wiring mechanism of standard page events in ASP.NET. It is exposed by `AutoEventWireup` attribute of the Page directive, and is by default set to `true` for every new page. Say if you have a handler

```
protected void Page_Load(object source, EventArgs e)
```

wire-up mechanism will identify it and bind to a Load event of the page. This mechanism is specific to pages only, and does not spread on controls inside those pages.